# Additional drivers for Nvidia Card does nothing with Blender

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, blender, additional-drivers

Ubuntu 16.04
I'm trying to update my graphic card.
I choose the nVidia driver like the picture below, then I hit Apply changes.

[image]

It takes couple of seconds it just revert back to the X.org X server like nothing has happened, with the following error.

[image]

(note: I'm already connected to the internet and have done the sudo update/upgrade commands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Determine the latest version of Nvidia driver available for your graphics card

​a. Visit the graphics drivers PPA homepage [here](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and determine the latest versions of Nvidia drivers available which is ‘nvidia-370’ as of January 1, 2017.

b. Verify that your graphics card is capable of running the latest drivers. You can search on this [link](http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html) to determine if your graphics card is supported by a driver version. Don’t be so particular about the version part after the dot (after nvidia-370.xxx), just make sure you’re supported on the main version 370.

2. Remove older Nvidia driver

​ If your graphic is supported, you can go ahead and remove all previously installed Nvidia drivers on your system. Enter the following command in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

3. Add the graphics drivers PPA

​Let us go ahead and add the graphics-driver PPA -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers

sudo apt-get update
```

4. Install (and activate) the latest Nvidia graphics drivers. Enter System Settings/Software&Updates/Additional Drivers Tab following to install the version of Nvidia graphics supported by your graphics card
   [image]
5. Reboot your computer for the new driver to kick-in. You can check your installation status with the following command

`lsmod | grep nvidia`

If there is no output, then your installation has probably failed. It is also possible that the driver is not available in your system's driver database. You can run the following command to check if your system is running on the open source driver nouveau. If the output is negative for nouveau, then all is well with your installation.

```
lsmod | grep nouveau
```

6. Prevent automatic updates that might break the drivers by removing the graphics-drivers PPA from your software sources On Ubuntu, go to your software sources, and then other sources and remove all instances of the graphics-driver PPAs.
7. Removal

​Are you running into issues with the new drivers, you can easily remove it.
       a. Remove the graphics-drivers PPA as indicated in the step above.
        b. Enter the following command to completely remove the driver
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
       c. Reboot your PC for the open-source nouveau drivers to kick-in.

[Source](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux)

Also, In order for Blender to Detect the NVidia Driver, you must Download the Latest Version of Blender from [Here](https://www.blender.org/download/).

Or update the Ubuntu Repository by adding the Following PPA For Ubuntu 16.04 and Removing the Outdated Version of Blender: For Other Distros follow [Here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/09/blender-2-79-released-install-it-in-ubuntu/).

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove blender

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thomas-schiex/blender

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install blender
```

After that Blender Detects the Video Card without any Problems!
[image]